# Dotnet core CORs issue when calling from other application with Same Domain

Tags: .net-core, content-security-policy

We have a dotnet core application hosted in IIS, with url of format application1.domain.com. We have added

```
options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .WithOrigins(webURL,"https://*.domain.com")   
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
                    });
```

Also have this,

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.domain.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.domain.com data:; connect-src 'self' *.domain.com; form-action 'self' ;");}
```

We are getting this below error in chrome, when `https://application2.domain.com/` application try to load `https://application1.domain.com/angular.js` inside their html file.

> Refused to load the script 'https://{application}.domain.com/angular.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) ajax.googeapis.com *.api.splkmobile.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Any other settings need to be done from `https://application2.domain.com` end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show the CSP having `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';` but violation occurs at `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googeapis.com *.api.splkmobile.com`.
This means other CSP is published somewhere, and CSP you shown is not published.

You have to find where really CSP header is issued and add `https://application2.domain.com` into it.

Comment: While loading the library angular.min.js file its throwing the CSP error... We dont have www.google-analytics.com and other domains as seen in error any where in our code. Thats where we couldnt proceed further..

Comment: This error can occur in the CSP of a third party frame. Or a browser plugin might embed something. If there are no third-party frames on the page, this is your CSP.